# How to delete mysql when check radio button using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to delete mysql when check radio button using ajax ?

http://jsfiddle.net/5rfg9cyu/

after i checked radio button `SECOND RADIO`

i want to delete mysql like this

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM procust_store_1  WHERE products_id = '$_POST[products_id]' AND user = '$id' "; $objQuery = mysql_query($sql);
```

and if checked radio button `FIRST RADIO`

i want to delete mysql like this

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM procust_store_2  WHERE products_id = '$_POST[products_id]' AND user = '$id' "; $objQuery = mysql_query($sql);
```

....

How can i do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".radio_id").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="first"){
                $("#second_checkbox").hide();                
                $("#first_checkbox_display").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="second"){
                $("#first_checkbox_display").hide();                
                $("#second_checkbox").show();    
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<form id="first_checkbox_display" name="form1" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" style=" margin: 0px; " >
<input type="text" name="products_id" value="1294759">
<input type="text" name="products_color" value="red">
<input type="text" name="products_type" value="electronic">
<input type="button" value="Check1" onclick="doajax_products_check()"/>
<p id="myplace_data1"></p>
</form>



<form id="second_checkbox" name="form2" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" style=" display: none; margin: 0px; " >
<input type="text" name="products_id" value="0000000">
<input type="text" name="products_color" value="iiiiiii">
<input type="text" name="products_type" value="aaaaaaa">
<input type="button" value="Check2" onclick="doajax_products_check2()"/>
<p id="myplace_data2"></p>
</form>


<label><input type="radio" class="radio_id" name="colorRadio" value="first" checked >FIRST RADIO</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" class="radio_id" name="colorRadio" value="second">SECOND RADIO</label>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Try using `mysqli_*`

Comment: and your query is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: and vuln is: ' OR 1=1/*